# How do I schedule a task to run at a fixed time in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, scheduled-tasks

I want to automate running few functions at a particular time in my discord bot.
I tried the following where `func` is a function that I want to run.

```py
class Scheduler(commands.Cog):
    """Schedule various commands"""

    def __init__(self):
        # Run Schdelued Tasks
        print("Running Scheduled Tasks")
        self.scheduled.start()

    # Scheduled tasks
    @tasks.loop(seconds = 30)
    async def scheduled(self):
        func()
```

However, upon running, I am getting this error:

```
Running Scheduled Tasks
/app/bot/cogs/core/core.py:59: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
    func()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

What should I do? I have also heard of `APScheduler`, should I go with that or use `tasks.loop()` only?

Comment: If you want to schedule at on modays at 3 am for example. Use `APScheduler`, if you want to run it every thirty minutes for example. use tasks. Anyways, could u send the full traceback?

Comment: @Ceres Thank you for the help. How would the code look like in `APScheduler`? Also this is the only error I am getting. There is nothing else in the console.

Comment: you have to use the `traceback` module to print the entire traceback, as the error tells you

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/40873438.html) and `APS` docs might be helpful

Comment: The error tells you that `func` is a coroutine and it should be awaited, instead of `func()` simply `await func()`